# Changing the width according to the rating ng-style Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, width, ng-style

I am trying to change the width of this span according to the rating. The 'quality' in this case is from 1 to 5. If the rating is 5 the width should be 100%. How can i bind this with ng-style?

```
<span class="rating-box" ng-style="{ 'width': {{star.quality*20}} + '%' }"></span>
```

This code is not working. I am getting this error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-style' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ("      <small>Calitate</small>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: which angular version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Angular 8

Comment: then you need [ngStyle] not ng-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is syntax mistake for angular 8 you need to use

```
<span class="rating-box" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': star.quality*20 + '%' }"></span>
```

Comment: It's not working either (see the error in the comment below)

Comment: remove "{{" and "}}"

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is :
`<span class="rating-box" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': star.quality*20 + '%' }"></span>`

You can find the selector definition of this directive in the official docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: It's not working, i'm getting this error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 11 in [{ 'width': {{star.quality*20}} + '%' }] in ng:///AppModule/DocumentItemComponent.html@144:48 ("litate</small>